# How to save an array with float values into a text file that is readable by Mac?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, save

I want to save float values stored in an array into a text file and read the file directly on Mac. This is how I create the array:

```
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *numObj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.14];
[dataArray insertObject:numObj atIndex:0];
NSNumber *numObj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.3];
[dataArray insertObject:numObj atIndex:1];
...
```

This is how I save the array:

```
NSData *savedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dataArray];
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/smith/Desktop/dataArray.txt";
[savedData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
```

When I open the file, the contents are just garbled letters. Instead, I want to make it something like this:

```
3.14
2.3
1.4
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `componentsJoinedByString:` to make an in-memory representation first, and then write that representation into a file, like this:

```
NSString *fileRep = [dataArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/smith/Desktop/dataArray.txt";
[fileRep writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
```

This assumes that the number of items is relatively small, because the string representation is created entirely in memory.

Reading back is not as nice as writing out, though: you start by reading back a string, theb split it to components using `[fileRep componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]`, and then go through components in a loop or with a block, adding `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[element doubleValue]]` for each element of your split.

Answer (score 3):

the program you've written saves the object representation as an array of NSNumbers, while
the result you want/expect is a text file separated by newlines.

to save those float values into a text file of that format, you could to this:

```
...
NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString new];
[string appendFormat:@"%f\n", 3.14];
[string appendFormat:@"%f\n", 2.3];

NSError * error = nil;
BOOL written = [string writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:someEncoding error:&error];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create an XML plist from it to make it human-readable:

```
[dataArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This creates a property list, which is human-readable XML (except if the file already exists AND it's a binary plist, in this case the new plist will also be binary).

Comment: I suppose that this method must be faster then using the strings. But if I am testing a program on an iPhone while it's connected to Mac with cable, may I somehow save the XML file on Mac?

Comment: Well, not the most comfortable but definitely working solution. Thank you.